# Windows 7 (64-bit) compatibility of VBA/Excel and Access applications

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, 64-bit, microsoft-access, vba

I am currently investigating the possible issues when migrating from Windows XP 32bit to Windows 7 64-bit. The scope is MS Excel (32-bit), MS Access (32-bit) using VBA/Macros addins, ODBC and all related issues.

For example: if you use excel (32-bit) and oracle 32-bit odbc driver.
There is an issue described at: http://www.dbmotive.com/oracle_error_codes.php?type=ORA&errcode=6413

are there any (other) known issues / resources / websites / tools about this ?

Comment: That's an error in the programming of the Oracle ODBC driver, since "(" and ")" are perfectly valid characters on Windows. That is, this is not a 64-bit issue at all -- the problem would occur on 32-bit Windows if you installed the ODBC driver in a folder with "(" or ")" in the name.

Comment: I agree that this is not directly related to 64 bit. But It does occur on a 64 bit windows system with office 32 bit installed, default in "program files (x86)". So in my opinion it is an issue occurring on windows 7 64 bit. You know any other issues ? and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to Excel, but for Access, these are my links for 64-bit issues:

- [Compatibility Between the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx)
- [Office 2010 - about the 64-bit version](https://office-watch.com/2010/office-2010-about-the-64-bit-version/)
- [Installing Office 2010 64-bit](https://office-watch.com/2010/installing-office-2010-64-bit/)
- [Office 32-bit or 64-bit - which version is installed?](https://office-watch.com/2010/office-32-bit-or-64-bit-which-version-is-installed/)
- [Office 32 and 64 bit on the same machine](https://office-watch.com/2010/office-32-and-64-bit-on-the-same-machine/)
- [Preparing for Office 2010 64-bit](https://office-watch.com/2010/preparing-for-office-2010-64-bit/)
- [64-bit Office - is it worth the trouble?](https://office-watch.com/2010/64-bit-office-is-it-worth-the-trouble/)

Comment: thx for the reply.addition: the scope is office 2007 (32-bit), so no 64-bit office. This is not an option.

Comment: There are no issues with 32-bit Office (or any other 32-bit apps) running on Windows 64-bit, so far as I know. The only place there can be issues is if your apps depend on outside components that won't run on 64-bit Windows. Out-of-box, there are no such dependencies in Office 2007. And so far as I know, it's pretty hard to break a 32-bit app under 64-bit Windows unless the app is doing the kind of stuff that is hardwired in a way that won't run inside the 32-bit subsystem. That would likely indicate a poorly-written program that should be replaced with something better.

Comment: Also, I wasn't even beginning to suggest using 64-bit Office. Had you read any of the links after the first, you'd know that.